# How do I create second target in my project to create a pre-populated database for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I currently have an iOS app that can 'bootstrap' it's database from a bunch of pList files (which I use during development when there are db changes) or copy a pre-existing database for the first run on a device (I use the database that was created in the simulator).

This is getting messy: I have to flip flags to decide whether I'm bootstrapping or not, I don't want to distribute a 'bootstrap' version by accident, and I don't want to distribute the plists either (then the target device would have 3 copies of the data: the bundled db, the plists, and the writeable copy of the db).

What I would like to do is create a separate desktop app that uses the same object model. The plists would be used by the desktop app, which I would run to generate the db (or maybe even provide a GUI for DB tweaks!). The iPhone and desktop app would share the same data model. And the desktop app would write to the db that's bundled with the iOS app, so I don't have to remember to copy from the simulator.

So far, I have been able to find posts that say that this would be trivial to do... but a tutorial or tips would be helpful.

Comment: There used to be this very handy trick where you could option-drag CoreData objects from the model into a nib file to auto generate UI, but I don't seem to be able to find the equivalent in Xcode 4. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sasha,

I made a new target in my existing project and was able to create my bootstrapped Core Data DB. It wasn't hard at all. You reuse most of your existing code.

Andrew

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It sounds like you're doing exactly what I want to do, but I'm not sure what to do after I've added a second target to the project. (All of my projects so far have been pretty simple single-target apps). Any pointers you could provide (including just where to look in the documentation, if that's easiest) on how to set up my second target once I've created it would be most helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Sasha, A target is just a collection of code and build rules. It is pretty well documented in Apple's various pieces of Xcode documentation. In your case, you want to build an app that creates the DB with all of your flags set the appropriate way. If you're building an iOS app, then you probably want to run in the simulator. Once you're finished building the app, you place it with your other resources and then write some code to move it out of the bundle and into the documents folder. Then it will behave as if it was created there in the first place. Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You have many options. You can create a side-by-side application whose sole responsibility is to pre-populate the DB in your main app. Or you can use a script to populate the DB file directly. I am including a link to a nice tutorial that describes the latter approach.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data

Comment: Thanks Perception. Ray Wenderlinch has some really great tutorials. The only trouble with this one is it has you messing with the schema in sqlite, which may work but isn't supported by Apple so could bite you down the road. But believe me, that's not to say I haven't been tempted, it would be soooo much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've seen this problem dealt with in projects that I've worked on is simple. Make two targets, and configure each one with the appropriate flags. You'll have your "flag flipping", but won't be quite as complicated and you'll be able to easily tell which one you are building.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it sounds as if you can create the Core Data Persistent Store on the desktop. (The caveat here is to ensure you are using a shared Core Data Model.)

Given that, you should bundle the DB as an application resource and copy it into place if it is not found at application startup.

Something like this should do you:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    if (![self persistentStoreExists]) { // First run.
        [self copyPersistentStoreFromBundleResources];
    }

    // ... continue here.

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark First Run Core Data Import 

- (BOOL)persistentStoreExists
{
    NSString *storePath = [[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite" ] path]; 
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    return [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath];
}

- (void)copyPersistentStoreFromBundleResources
{
    NSLog(@"Installing default DB from bundle.");

    NSString *storePath = [[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite" ] path];

    NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                  pathForResource:@"MyApp" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    if (defaultStorePath == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error finding default store");
        return;
    } else {
        BOOL copiedDefaultStore = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                   copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath
                                   toPath:storePath
                                   error:nil];
        if (! copiedDefaultStore) {
            NSLog(@"Error copying default store");
            return;
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application's Documents directory

/**
 Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Carlton. I have the startup code working ok to copy the DB if it doesn't exist (although at a glance what you've got here looks cleaner, I may use it instead). The issue I'm having is with generating the DB to begin with, and sharing the data model between the two apps. I'll go clarify this in the original question...